# Windows 10 Display is not on the correct Resolution before user login

Tags: windows, display, resolution

This issue has been annoying me very much. I search on MSDN, support.microsoft.com, but I keep getting answers such as "my display resolution won't change in settings" type of thing. But mine is different: I have a QHD 2560x1440 display, but the problem is, the resolution only changes after I login. For example:

> Press the Power button --> BIOS boots --> Windows Lockscreen on 1920x1080 --> logs on to my user --> resolution changes to 2560x1440.

Why is this so? I want the crisp lock screen quality of QHD but I get 1920x1080 instead. I suspect that there is a user setting that changes the resolution upon login. But I want the global resolution to be 2560x1440, not 1920x1080. Is there a registry value somewhere or can I write a PS script to set the global resolution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a guess.. look and see if you have something stupid by the gfx card manufacturer running in startup.  Move this to a task that runs "whether a user is logged on or not".  That would be my first approach without knowing more.

Comment: Where do I search that? Nothing found related to NVIDIA in Task scheduler.

Comment: Check out [this free app](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) from sysinternals/microsoft.  It will show you everything at startup and more.  You *could* just look at the task manager -> advanced -> startup tab but it won't show you the parameters being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Parsec was enabled before I logged on. Therefore, thru some oddity, Parsec set my resolution to its default 1920x1080. I deleted Parsec RDP and rebooted. Everything worked again.